# Why are there upvotes without reputation in a user's profile?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I have noticed graphs like this in few Stack Overflow top user profiles.

- Why are some posts not getting reputation?
- Why are users not getting it, even if they're worth it?
- Is there any daily limit for reputation? Or any rules?

[image]

Then on an another day

[image]

Comment: [check these profiles 1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=reputation&sort=time), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation) ,[3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov?tab=reputation)

Comment: Yes. There is a reputation cap which is why those posts don't show any reputation. See [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Simple explanation: *Question doesn't show research effort*.

Comment: I didn't downvote but presume because of the lack of any apparent research effort. You even tagged it `daily-reputation-limit` but don't seem to have looked at any of the previous questions in the tag.

Comment: Please check the edits. After edits only it came as in this form..

Comment: Seems to me that recently this upvotes without reputation don't snow anymore?

Comment: This question was asked more than 7 years back, information in it might have got outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any daily limit for reputations

Yes, there is. Maximum of 200 reputation for upvotes. It has been there from day one.

See [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for details.

Comment: Is this limit still exists?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe this changed?